# how to include Android gradle dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin

I have created  simple android eclipse project. Then I added build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
  }
}

task listJars << {
    configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.path }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 17
  buildToolsVersion '17'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }


  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      resources.srcDirs = ['src']
      renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    instrumentTest {
      java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
      res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['tests/assets']
      resources.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0' 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }
}
```

As you can see, I want to use RoboGuice from maven. Gradle downloads it, but does not add to the lib folder for eclipse. So I cannot use it in eclipse when writing code. Do I need to manually copy them over? I added a task to display them:

```
$ gradle -q listJars
/Users/xxx/Documents/codepath2/SampleAndroidGradle/libs/android-support-v4.jar
/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/org.roboguice/roboguice/2.0/jar/727ccb8f376109d0b5c44abca6f791dccc5c5dbc/roboguice-2.0.jar
/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/jar/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar
/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/jar/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar
/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/asm/asm/3.1/jar/c157def142714c544bdea2e6144645702adf7097/asm-3.1.jar
/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/org.sonatype.sisu.inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/jar/7ce5e983fd0e6c78346f4c9cbfa39d83049dda2/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar
/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/com.google.inject/guice/3.0/jar/28586dc97c525501329d9a242fc3402041e3572d/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. Gradle won't put the jars in the lib directory. The assumption is that your lib directory is for manual changing jars. You can probably create a Gradle task to copy them to your lib directory if thats what oyu want to do.

I don't think there is official support for gradle in eclipse, and if you're just starting out a new project, consider using Android Studio (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following post includes two Groovy fragments which can be added to `build.gradle`. Either of them makes gradle dependencies available to Eclipse.

See [Add dependencies via gradle to eclipse in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709305)