# Android error on imported module build,gradle - Could not find method instrumentTestCompile()

Tags: android, gradle

On import [ListViewAnimation](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/issues) library, I get rebuild error

```
Error:(7) A problem occurred evaluating project ':library'.
```

> Could not find method instrumentTestCompile() for arguments [org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5, build_n73cqp2judtlhpna5h10rio8c$_run_closure1_closure3@20e75be5] on project ':library'.

This is the imported module build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'android-library'


dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    instrumentTestCompile ('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5')  { exclude group: 'org.hamcrest' }
    instrumentTestCompile ('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0')  { exclude group: 'org.hamcrest' }
    instrumentTestCompile ('junit:junit:4.11')  { exclude group: 'org.hamcrest' }
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        instrumentTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(new Date().format('yyyyMMddHH'))
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'
```

What is the problem  ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*instrumentTest* has been renamed in *androidTest* in recent android-gradle-plugin

You have to rename in the build.gradle :

- *instrumentTestCompile* --> *androidTestCompile*
- *instrumentTest* --> *androidTest*

Comment: Thanks! that works.
It also throw me an error on VERIOSN_NAME that does not exist, so I've added to gradle.Project this value with dummy number.
But, now it throws compile error:
Error:(44) A problem occurred evaluating project ':library'.
> Could not read script 'C:\Users\egabay\AndroidStudio\Journey\maven_push.gradle' as it does not exist.
Do I need to install something ?

Comment: The library depends on `gradle.properties`, which should reside in the parent folder of `library`. Copy the `gradle.properties` from the root of the repo to that parent folder and it should work.