# How to create .aar file of Android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, aar

I want to create .aar file for using our project with all activity and resource to other project just like .jar file, but jar file does not contain resource folder that's why i am unable to get xml files.

Please help me.

Comment: If you project is a library project, it should have an `AAR` file generated by the build process... Please show us what you've tried and give us more details as yo how you build your application/library.

Comment: see these links, might be helpful..
1) http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/aar-for-Eclipse


2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709305/add-dependencies-via-gradle-to-eclipse-in-android-project