# Consuming aars from eclipse does not work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, aar

***THIS PART WAS MY ORIGINAL STARTING PROBLEM. PLEASE READ THE UPDATES**
I have imported an android project in eclipse that apparently depends on [rengwuxian](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText).
Since I could not find the jar and did not know how else to do it, I followed the instructions in [consuming-aars-eclipse](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) and imported a second project with the artifacts from the aar as an android eclipse project as well.

Then in my original project that I got compilation errors for `com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText` in my layout files I added this newly created from the aar project as a reference (Project->Properties->Build Path->Add Project)

The compilation errors got resolved! *But* in my layout files now everywhere that is defined the element `com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText` I get errors in the resource definitions.

Eg.the following:

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'baseColor' in
>   package   'com.test

The attibute it seems to complaint about is:

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            .....
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            app:baseColor="@color/text_color"
            app:primaryColor="@color/text_color" />
```

---> app:baseColor="@color/text_color"

This `@color/text_color` is defined in my original application in the original application's package and apparently the classes in the aar imported project (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) can not see/access these resources.

How can I fix this? Or is there another better way for my problem?

Note: I also tried adding a source link to the folder of my project's res/ folder but did not solve this.

**Update:**
I removed the reference to the project and add the classes.jar to the build path (this jar was inside the aar project). Same issue

**UPDATE 2:**
I found this that helps to import aars to eclipse [aar-for-eclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/aar-for-Eclipse). I copy/pasted the code snippets (task copyJarDependencies etc) in the folder but I got an exception:

> No such property: libDir for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy_Decorated

So I added a def in the line `libDir = new File(project.projectDir, '/libs')
Then this worked but I got:

> Could not find property 'compile' on configuration container

How can fix this? I am not sure what to declare or what is missing

**Update 3:**
I added `apply plugin: 'java'` and the compile attribute is ok now but I get:

> configurations.releaseCompile.filter {it.name.endsWith 'jar'}.each { File file -> moveJarIntoLibs(file)}

How can I fix this so that it works?
I am using this project ---> https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText
And this post ---> http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/aar-for-Eclipse

Comment: Try `android:baseColor` instead

Comment: @Apurva:Now I get same error but package 'android'

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem with gradle but on android studio. Solution for me was to use

`configurations.releaseCompile.filter {it.name.endsWith 'jar'}.each {moveJarIntoLibs(it)}`

instead of:

`configurations.releaseCompile.filter {it.name.endsWith 'jar'}.each { File file -> moveJarIntoLibs(file)}`

And remember not to apply java and android plugin in the same project, because it won't work (see gradle with --debug --stacktrace )