# How to import TangoUX correctly into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-project-tango

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to add the TangoUXLayout tag to my activity's xml file and attempt to run the project.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.atap.tango.uxsupportlibrary.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/libtango_device.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.tangoproject.experiments.javapointcloud-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tangoproject.experiments.javapointcloud-2, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

The documentation is specific to android studio and gradle, but I'm having issues w/ the NDK and pcl in android studio so I'm forced to use eclipse. I have added the jar to the build path, and when I remove the following from the XML file I can use the TangoUx object to detect exceptions.

```
    <com.google.atap.tango.ux.TangoUxLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_tango"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I think `TangoUX` dependency can not be resolved as Eclipse does not support `AAR` extension for libraries. The post from @[Rafael](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16762533/194894) may solve it. I personally haven't tried this approach. I may give it a try it in few days.

Comment: From what I found you can actually unzip the `AAR` file and find the `JAR` within it. I'm actually able to use the library in my activity, but using parts of it in the XML file causes the app to crash