# Eclipse : Add zendesk sdk into android project

Tags: android, eclipse, zendesk, zendesk-api

Hi Everyone,

Iam trying to add zendesk contact us and help functionality in my
android project which i create using eclipse, they are giving sdk for Android studio but there is no any stand alone sdk which i can add in eclipse, can any one guide me how to get that stand alone sdk.

Thanks 
Aadil

Comment: you should move to android studio for better development experience! Make copy of your project and try this https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Comment: I would love to work with android studio but this is very old project they are not allowing me to convert that on studio.

Comment: whats the system is saying?

Comment: @SohailZahid Thank you for your concern i had solve that issue.

Comment: how you solved? if you add your solution by answering your own question it would help others.

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23179828/803062

Comment: add this in as answer to your own question.

Comment: Finally i got the solution through this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709305/add-dependencies-via-gradle-to-eclipse-in-android-project/23179828#23179828](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709305/add-dependencies-via-gradle-to-eclipse-in-android-project/23179828#23179828)